# How to get list of all devices in my network Using Bonjour

Tags: ios, wifi

I want to know  users In my network Using Bonjour
1. list of All users 
2. list if Idevices Users(iPhone,ipad,ipd)

i don’t know exactly how it works. here is my code http://pastie.org/9366751#75

Now i am  getting only mydevicename.local in “seevices Array”;

i think i have to change some thing in the below line

```
[self.browser searchForServicesOfType:@"_MyService._tcp." inDomain:@"local"];
```

if i use _services._dns-sd._udp. getting error code 72004
if i use "_music._tcp." and _ipp._tcp. getting my name only

what to use to get all the devieces  and only idevices

i have seen App  which exactly meets my requirement Fing(https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/fing-network-scanner/id430921107?mt=8)

how they get that list any tutorial will be helpful.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
[self.browser searchForServicesOfType:@"_services._dns-sd._udp." inDomain:@""];
```

Just look Apple wiTap sample once.You can get enough reference .http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: thanks for reply, even if i run witap i am getting only myname.ocal in the list

Comment: [self.netServiceBrowser searchForServicesOfType:@"_printer._tcp" inDomain:@""];
By using this i can get all available printers from my network

Comment: nice, then how can get all devices

Comment: sry i am new to developemnt,is there any conventions to get the names like printres

Comment: try this @"_services._dns-sd._udp." instead of @"_printer._tcp".i think it will work.let me know the result

Comment: tried no use, and also tried with _music._tcp. gives only mymane